# How to encrypt GET url for search in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, routes, laravel-5.5

I am getting stuck on this problem, I don't know hot to encrypt the **URL** for search in Laravel 5.5... the result like this :

`localhost:8000/Akademik/Mahasiswa?cari=some_keyword`

but I want like this :

`localhost:8000/Akademik/Mahasiswa?cari=some_encrypted_keyword`

like :

`localhost:8000/Akademik/Mahasiswa?cari=Kas6F8ajhasdhhfbdgshek`

this my **MahasiswaController.php**

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{   
    if ($request->get('cari') == null) {

        $datas = Mahasiswa::paginate(10);
        return view('Akademik.Mahasiswa.mahasiswaIndex', compact('datas'))->with('no',($request->input('page',1)- 1)*10);

    } else {
        $cari = $request->get('cari');
        $datas = Mahasiswa::where('nama','LIKE','%'.$cari.'%')->paginate(10);
        return view('Akademik.Mahasiswa.mahasiswaIndex', compact('datas'))->with('no',($request->input('page',1)- 1)*10);

    }
}
```

This my **route/web.php**

```
Route::Resource('Akademik/Mahasiswa','Akademik\Mahasiswa\MahasiswaController');
```

and This my **mahasiswaIndex.blade.php** (search form)

```
 <div class="col s4 m6 right">
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'Akademik/Mahasiswa','method' => 'get')) }}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
             {{ Form::text('cari',null,['id' => 'cari','class' => 'col s12']) }}
           <label for="cari">Cari</label>
          </div>
        </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need to encrypt it if you use a POST request, and https

Comment: Where's your attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: @LukePark I was try search and googling for 2 day ,,, but did not get any solution ,,sorry I am new in laravel

Comment: @MarkBaker is that enough secure?

Comment: Unless you set it up incorrectly, it's secure enough for sending passwords... it's the same method that my bank uses

Comment: thanks for answering maybe someday I will juse https but for now I just still learn laravel... in my localhost.. :)

Comment: Can I suggest [re-thinking whether or not encryption is the right tool for the job of passing URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to encrypt your input field. you must do in javascript/jquery AJAX before Sending the keyword to url result. let assume you have controller and route to make encryption like this :

```
localhost:8000/Akademik/encrypt
```

after that, you will get the keyword encrypted on var some_encrypted_keyword then send again via Ajax GET to url :

```
localhost:8000/Akademik/Mahasiswa?cari=some_encrypted_keyword
```

ask me anything. hope this is solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt your url parameter and decrypt it in your controller. You can try this:

In your view: Suppose your parameter is cari or more parameter you can encrypt.

```
<?php
        $parameter =[
            'cari' => (value of input field),
        ];
    $parameter= Crypt::encrypt($parameter);
?>
<a href="{{url('/url/',$parameter)}}" target="_blank">a link</a>
```

Your route will be:

```
Route::get('/url/{parameter}', 'YourController@methodName');
```

In your controller, You can decrypt your parameter:

```
public function methodName($cari){
    $data = Crypt::decrypt($cari);
  }
```

You must be use `Crypt` `namespace` in your top of controller as

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
```

**Note**: You can encrypt url parameter with `Crypt::encrypt($parameter)` and decrypt with `Crypt::decrypt($parameter)`

Comment: thanks for answering,,,how to send input field data to this parameter `'cari' => (value of input field)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is actually what you need? For security considerations HTTPS protocol is used, which encrypts all the communication between client side and the server. If you simply want to hide raw data from your browser address bar, you might you POST method instead of GET.

Comment: thanks for answering..yes .. this is just for learning purpose only ...because i am new in laravel.. :)